# LINQ Current record and x number of records on either side

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Terms>` with `Id`, `StartDate` and `EndDate` in `Terms`.

I want to filter the `List` using LINQ to the current term and also return `x` number of records on either side of the current term.

Essentially a method called `GetTerms(cntBefore, cntAfter)` would need to:

1. Query the `Terms` data
2. Find current term `StartDate <= DateTime.Now <= EndDate`
3. Order by `StartDate` asc
4. Return `cntBefore` number of previous records
5. Return `cntAfter` number of next records

In theory, `GetTerms(4,3)` would return a list of 8 records:

- `[1, 2, 3, 4, Current, 1, 2, 3]`

What would be the best way to accomplish this using LINQ?  Thank you

Comment: Do you work on object (`List<T>`) or on a BDD (you put the *entity-framework* tag here) ?

Comment: Hi @Orace, I work on object.  Not BDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work in a list, use the indices is pretty straightforward:

```
// We suppose data is sorted by StartDate 
IList<Term> GetNeighborhood(IList<Term> data, int beforeCount, int afterCount)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var current = data.Single(d => d.StartDate <= now && now <= d.EndDate);
    var currentIndex = data.IndexOf(current);

    var startIndex = Math.Max(0, currentIndex - beforeCount);
    var endIndex = Math.Min(data.Count, currentIndex + afterCount);
    var resultCount = endIndex - startIndex + 1;

    return data.Skip(startIndex).Take(resultCount).ToList();
}
```

If the `current` term is too close of the beginning or the end of the list, the returned list size will not be `beforeCount + afterCount + 1` but less end the position of the `current` term in this list can be anything.

Comment: Thank you @Orace...  I should have thought of this :)  Appreciate it